# How to "unmaximize" Electron window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've tried something like this:

```
function maximizeApp(){
    if (remote.getCurrentWindow().isMinimized()) {
        remote.getCurrentWindow().unmaximize();
    } else {
        remote.getCurrentWindow().maximize();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it just only maximize the window.

Comment: Okay, so i've typed `isMinimized()`, instead of `isMaximized()` -_-

Answer (score 0):

try `remote.getCurrentWindow().restore();`
this worked for me